# Unit Testing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am testing my index action which contains some global variables. I have created few test methods for this index action. When I run these methods simultaneously, the values in global variable changes due to which my Asserts fail.

This is my Index Action:

```
 public class SetController : Controller
 {
    public static string PreviousOrder;
    public static int PreviousPageNumber = 1;
    public static bool orderBy = true;

     public ActionResult Index(string Filter_Value, int? Page_No, string Sorting_Order, bool? OrderBy, string faqSetCreated)
    {
        int No_Of_Page = (Page_No ?? 1);
        if (No_Of_Page == PreviousPageNumber)
        {
            if (Sorting_Order == PreviousOrder)
            {
                if (OrderBy != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)OrderBy)
                    {
                        orderBy = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderBy = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                orderBy = true;
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

This is my Test Method:

```
   public void Faq_Set_Index_Test_With_No_Parameter_Passed_Returning_Model()
         {
        //Arrange
        string Filter_Value = null;
        int? Page_No = null;
        string Sorting_Order = null;
        bool OrderBy = false;
        string faqSetCreated = null;

        //Act
        var result = controller.Index(Filter_Value, Page_No, Sorting_Order, OrderBy, faqSetCreated) as ViewResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.ViewBag.OrderBy);
               }
```

When i run all the test methods together, after passing first test the values of global variable changes due to which my upcoming test gets changed values and cannot behave as expected

What should I do to so that the value of static variables remain same as the default values after each test run.

Comment: Your controller shouldn't even compile.  The method signature has a result type of `ActionResult` but there is no code that returns a value.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment - the current approach with static properties will not play well (I assume there is some part of code that is changing the value of those static fields in your action method, which is hidden for some reasons), as a single controller instance may be serving several requests simultaneously. It actually is happening when you're running several tests at once.

Comment: I have not posted whole action for bravity. Also All test methods are running simultaneously which is causing the static values to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most unit testing frameworks allow you to define a method which can run after each test by using an attribute, you could use this to reset your static values after each test. You haven't said which testing framework you're using, but with MSTest for example, the attribute would be `TestCleanup`.

```
[TestCleanup]
public void ResetDefaultValues()
{
    SetController.PreviousOrder = null;
    SetController.PreviousPageNumber = 1;
    SetController.orderBy = true;
}
```